# android opengl not rendering properly

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am having a problem when rendering a texture to the viewport.
The screen is being rendered but the texture (256*256) does not the same as the original jpg picture I uploaded.

Please find attached images and code for the render. One image is the original jpg and the other is screenshot that is the rendered texture on the android phone.

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylqRJ.jpg)

[rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXQcW.png)

This is my MainActivity code:

```
private void initialize() {
    if (hasGLES20()) {
        GLSurfaceView mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
        mGLView.setRenderer(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f,0.3f,0.8f,1.0f);


    String vertexShaderSource = "" +
    "uniform mat4 u_projection;" +
    "uniform mat4 u_model;" +
    "uniform mat4 u_view;" +
    "" +
    "attribute vec4 a_position;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +

    "" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "   gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_model * a_position;" +

    "   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +

    "}";

    String fragmentShaderSource = "" +

    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "" +
    "void main() {" +
    "   vec4 texCol = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
    "   gl_FragColor = texCol;" +

    "}";

    texture = new Texture(this);


    vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    String vertexShaderCompileLog = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);

    fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    String fragmentShaderCompileLog = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);

    programID = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(programID,vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(programID,fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "a_position");
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "a_texCoord");
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(programID);

    String programLinkLog = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(programID);

    float[] modelMatrix = new float[16], viewMatrix = new float[16], projectionMatrix  = new float[16];


    ByteBuffer modelMatrixByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(modelMatrix.length * 4);
    modelMatrixByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer modelMatrixBuffer = modelMatrixByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix,0);
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, modelMatrix,0,0,0,-2.0f);
    modelMatrixBuffer.put(modelMatrix);
    modelMatrixBuffer.rewind();

    // translate model to 0,0,-2
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix,0,0,0,0,0,0,-10,0,1,0);
    Matrix.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix,0,70,256/256,0.1f,100);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programID,"u_projection"),1,false,projectionMatrix,0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programID,"u_view"),1,false,viewMatrix,0);        
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programID,"u_model"),1,false,modelMatrixBuffer);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,256,256);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10){

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        float vertices[] =
        {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
        };

        float textureCoord[] =
        {
             0.0f,  1.0f,
             0.0f,  0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f,
             0.0f,  1.0f
        };


        ByteBuffer verticesByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        verticesByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = verticesByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.rewind();

        ByteBuffer textureCoordByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 4);
        textureCoordByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer textureCoordBuffer = textureCoordByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureCoordBuffer.put(textureCoord);
        textureCoordBuffer.rewind();

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, verticesBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, textureCoordBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);



    texture.setTexture();
    GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programID,"s_texture"),0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

This is my load Texture Class

```
public class Texture 
{
private int m_iTextureId;

public Texture(Context ctx)
{
  m_iTextureId = loadTexture(ctx, R.drawable.index);
}

public void setTexture()
{
  GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
  GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_iTextureId);
}

public int loadTexture(Context ctx, int rsrcId)
{
  int[] iTextureId = new int[1];
  GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
  GLES20.glGenTextures(1, iTextureId, 0);

  if(iTextureId[0] != 0)
  {
     GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, iTextureId[0]);

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
     options.inScaled = false;

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), rsrcId, 
                                                options);

     GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
     bitmap.recycle();

     GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                       GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                       GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

     GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                          GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                          GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

     GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
           GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
           GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  }
  else
  {
     throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture");
  }

  return iTextureId[0];
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: Which attached images? There are none.

Comment: sorry mate.  Just added it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are wrong. They contain the same coordinate twice:

```
float textureCoord[] =
{
     0.0f,  1.0f, <--
     0.0f,  0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f  <--
};
```

To solve this replace the last coordinate with [1, 0] instead of [0, 1].